# Eclipse fails retriving PHPEXcel Classes in debug mode

Tags: php, excel, eclipse, xdebug

I there
I'm facing a quite annoying problem... 
When I use Xdebug in Eclipse, it apparently ask absolutes paths in require_once statements. I can manually change my own files paths but PHPExcel Framework has an autoloader which uses only relatives paths. 
I don't know how to get rid of this ... 
Have you an idea ? Is there any setting in Eclipse to avoid this error ?